# Tensorflow multiplying 2D tensor elementwise with 3D tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

So I have a scenario where I have a CNN which branches into two parts. One part produces a tensor which is `x*y*300` representing a distribution of 300 classes for each `(x,y)`, the second part produces a tensor which is simply an `x*y*1` tensor such that each element is in range `[1,inf]`. Finally I want to multiply all 300 channel elements of each `(x,y)` coordinate in the first tensor by the value at `(x,y)` in the second tensor to produce a third tensor which is `x*y*300`. Simply put, I want to take each vertical vector slice of the first tensor and multiply that by the corresponding scalar in the second tensor. I've looked at the various functions of tensorflow and the closest function would by `tf.math.multiply` however this requires both tensors by the same dimension. How do I get around this while still making the network fully trainable end to end?

The reason I'm doing this arguably unusual operation is because I want to be able to perform annealed boltzmann softmax to refine the distribution for each `(x,y)` of the first tensor with a temperature value which is defined per pixel from the second tensor. Effectively learning the annealing temperature based on the features extracted in the second branch for each pixel.

Comment: @Lescurel ah, so it will automatically broadcast the x*y*1 to x*y*300 with respect to the multiplication. Will this still backpropagate correctly? I haven't found any information on how the auto-differentiation works when broadcasting occurs.

Comment: There should be no problem related to backprop.

Comment: @Lescurel thank you for your help. I marked the question as already answered as per suggestion.